# ¿Cómo puedo resetear o reiniciar un BehaviorSubject sin tener que volver a instanciar?

Tags: rxjs, observable

estoy tratando reiniciar un BehaviorSubject, que significa esto, que unsubscriba todos los observers y que pueda volver ha subscribirme con nuevos. actualmente tengo esto:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
const subject = new BehaviorSubject(0); // 0 is the initial value

subject.subscribe({
  next: v => console.log(`observerA: ${v}`)
});

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);

subject.subscribe({
  next: v => console.log(`observerB: ${v}`)
});

subject.next(3);
subject.unsubscribe();
subject.next(0);

subject.subscribe({
  next: v => console.log(`observerC: ${v}`)
});
```

pero no genera nuevamente el observe para C esta es la salida:

```
// Logs
// observerA: 0
// observerA: 1
// observerA: 2
// observerB: 2
// observerA: 3
// observerB: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes hacer lo que quieres porque cuando llamas a unsuscribe lo que haces es **cerrar** el objeto: no se producen más eventos y no te puedes volver a suscribir. Necesitas crear otra instancia:

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;
const {map} = rxjs.operators;


const subject = new BehaviorSubject(0); // 0 is the initial value

subject.subscribe({
  next: v => console.log(`observerA: ${v}`)
});

subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);

subject.subscribe({
  next: v => console.log(`observerB: ${v}`)
});

subject.next(3);
subject.unsubscribe();
try {
  subject.next(0);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("problema al usar next:", error.message);
}
try {
  subject.subscribe({
    next: v => console.log(`observerC: ${v}`)
  });
} catch(error2) {
  console.error("problema al intentar una suscripción:", error2.message);
}
```

```html
<script  src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.6.7/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Nota que este comportamiento es propio de `BehaviorSubject`, hay otros tipos de Observables (no es más que una interfaz) que admiten desuscripciones sin "romperse".